# What is an alternative for using a list in a dictionary to be able to reference the same list in different scopes?

Tags: python

I want an alternative to this approach:

```
a = {'_': [1, 2, 3]} 

def func(a: dict):   
    a['_'][1] = 3 

def func2(a: dict):   
    a['_'][0] = 3 
    func(a)  

func2(a)
```

```
>>> a 
{'_': [3, 3, 3]}
```

Comment: Everything you're doing could just be done with a global list `a = [1, 2, 3]`, you wouldn't even need the `global` keyword. But you should really think about whether global state is actually solving your problem.

Comment: What output/values do you want?

Comment: You mean you need to convert all members of a list value  of your dictionary to a specific number like `3`? or you don't want to use dictionary for your list?or what you exactly want to do?

Comment: @jonrsharpe I need to visualize quicksort with matplotlib and because I need recursion I think it's easiest to just have one list that gets passed down the scope.. But I don't really want to use a global list

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> What is an alternative for using a list in a dictionary to be able to reference the same list in different scopes?

Using a list...

```
a = [1, 2, 3]

def func(a: list):
    a[1] = 3

def func2(a: list):
    a[0] = 3
    func(a)  

func2(a)
```

```
>>> a 
[3, 3, 3]
```

Comment: oh.. but why did I think that this wouldn't work?

Comment: That's a question I really can't answer...

Comment: @davelopment In your code, `a['_']` gives exactly the same as `a` in mine. In other words it gives a reference to the list. So no need to use it in the first place

Comment: But is there a case where this is needed?

Comment: @davelopment Yes. Many. But not this one... If you have many lists and want to access them dynamically you can use a dict to access them with string names